# Anchoring Multiple Scenes in RealityKit

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

While loading multiple scenes (from reality composer) into arView, the scenes is not anchored in the same space.

In this example, scene1 is loaded when the app starts. After the button is pressed, the scene2 is added into the scene. In both the scenes, the models are placed at the origin and are expected to overlap with scene2 is added into the view. However, the position of scene1 and scene2 is different when they are added into the arView.

```
import UIKit  
import RealityKit  

class ViewController: UIViewController {  

    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!  
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!  

    var scene1: Experience.Scene1!  
    var scene2: Experience.Scene2!  

    override func viewDidLoad() {  
        super.viewDidLoad()  

        // Load the "Box" scene from the "Experience" Reality File  
        scene1 = try! Experience.loadScene1()  
        scene2 = try! Experience.loadScene2()  

        // Add the box anchor to the scene  
        arView.scene.addAnchor(scene1)  
    }  

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {  
        arView.scene.addAnchor(scene2)  
    }  

}
```

Note: This issues does not happen when both the scenes are added simultaneously.

How to make sure that both the scenes are anchored at the same ARAnchor?

Comment: What happens if you do `arView.scene.anchors.append(scene2)` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following strategy, in order to track a single anchor for both models:

```
let scene01 = try! Cube.loadCube()
let scene02 = try! Ball.loadSphere()

let cubeEntity = scene01.steelCube!.children[0] as! ModelEntity
let ballEntity = scene02.glassBall!.children[0] as! ModelEntity

// var cubeComp: ModelComponent = cubeEntity.components[ModelComponent].self!
// var ballComp: ModelComponent = ballEntity.components[ModelComponent].self!

let anchor = AnchorEntity(plane: .horizontal)
anchor.addChild(cubeEntity)
anchor.addChild(ballEntity)

// scene01.steelCube!.components.set(cubeComp)
// scene02.glassBall!.components.set(ballComp)

arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
```